# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0

```
 services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
           .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
           .AddMicrosoftGraph()
           .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I have this in my .net web application with required AzureAD information in the appsettings.

I use this to get an access token and call microsoft graph api. after an hour the token expires and does not use the refresh one to get another.

this is meant to to be automatically called? am I missing something

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "****************",
    "ClientId": "****************",
    "TenantId": "****************",
    "ClientSecret": "****************",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****************,
    "ResponseType": "code",
    "UsePkce": true,
    "Scopes": "**************** ,
    "TokenValidationParameters": {
      "NameClaimType": "name",
      "RoleClaimType": "roles"
    },
    "TokenAcquisitionOptions": {
      "RefreshBuffer": 120,
      "ForceRefreshOnExpiration": true
    }
  },
```

my appsettings to configure refresh token

Answer (score 0):

In startup.cs, make sure to send required scopes to                     EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() i.e something like                     `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)`

*Example:*

`.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] {"user.read", "xxx", "xxx"}).`

Grant admin consent to the scopes in azure portal.

[image]

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            });
           services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }
```

As you are using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication , the azure ad tokens, by default have expiration times and this can be changed by setting
***UseTokenLifetime to false***

Ex:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
              {
                  options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                  //change to false
              });
```

[image]

***appsettings.json:***

```
  {
      "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com",
        "ClientId": "50xxxxfbd2ed06e",
        "TenantId": "fb13xxx8f3b0",
        "ClientSecret": "Bxxxxag7",
        "ClientCertificates": [
        ],
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
      },
      "DownstreamApi": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
      },
```

**In your code, use as below**

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false; 
});
```

[image]

**Reference :** [UseTokenLifeTime behavior clarification after testing · Issue #37087 · dotnet/aspnetcore · GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37087)